# How to decode html content of arabics to display in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am getting response from api for arabics as like this.

```
 {"content":"&lt;div class=&quot;page-head&quot;&gt;\r\n&lt;h3&gt;\u0645\u0639\u0644\u0648\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0639\u0646\u0627&lt;\/h3&gt;\r\n&lt;h4 style=&quot;box-sizing: border-box; line-height: 1.5; margin: 0.8em 0px; font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.06em; color: #4f4f4f; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: #ffffff;&quot;&gt;\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0630\u0627 &quot;\u0645\u0646 \u0646\u062d\u0646&quot; \u0635\u0641\u062d\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u062e\u0648\u0631: \u0648\u0647\u0648 \u064a\u0631\u0648\u064a \u0644\u0646\u0627 \u0642\u0635\u0629.&lt;\/h4&gt;\r\n&lt;\/div&gt;\r\n&lt;div class=&quot;col2-set content-seperator&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/div&gt;","success":1,"error":false}
```

I parsed the content from response(for english, it's working fine) and for arabics, it's displaying as above content. When I use to display, it's showing in box format in webview. How to decode html and display in arabics?

This is what I used in android to load in webview.

```
       staticPage.loadData(
                Html.fromHtml( content)
                        .toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this setting before loading html

```
WebSettings settings = staticPage.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

and use charset=utf-8

```
staticPage.loadData(
            Html.fromHtml( content)
                    .toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```